# Minimizar janela jfx

Tags: java, javafx

Minha janela está sem as bordas do sistema.

```
primaryStage.initStyle(StageStyle.UNDECORATED);
```

Criei um botão para minimizar a janela mas encontro *exception* ao atribuir para a minha `stage`:

```
@FXML
void btnMinimizarOnAction(ActionEvent event) throws IOException
{
    Stage stage = (Stage) btnMinimizar.getScene().getWindow();
    stage.setIconified(true);
}
```

Existe alguma outra forma de fazer isso?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Podem existir maneiras diferentes de obter o `Stage`, mas o método `setIconified(true)` deve ser chamado.